Prove or disprove that function $r\mapsto\frac{M(r,f)}{r^k}$ is increasing for transcendental entire function $f$ and fixed $k>0$.
Prove or disprove that function
$$r\mapsto\frac{M(r,f)}{r^k},\quad (\text{here}\ M(r,f)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|)$$ is increasing for transcendental entire function $f$ and fixed $k>0$ when $r$ large enough.
First, it is easy to see that $M(r,f)$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ by maximum modulus principle. Also when $f=P$ is a polynomial of degree $$, we have some results in an old post prove that function is increasing/decreasing.
So I want to study, when $f$ is transcendental entire function $f$, the monotonicity of
$$r\mapsto\frac{M(r,f)}{r^k},$$
where $k$ is a fixed positive number.
I can prove that $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{M(r,f)}{r^k}=\infty.$$
But how to prove the monotonicity. Some known result(may help): $\log M(r,f)$ is a convex function of $\log r$.
Any hints and conments will welcome, thanks for for your attention.

Yes, for a transcendental entire function $f$ and a positive number $k$ is $r \mapsto M(r, f)/r^k$ eventually (strictly) increasing. We need two facts for the proof:

The Hadamard three-circle theorem, which states that $\log M(r, f)$ is a convex function of $\log r$.
$\lim_{r \to \infty} \log M(r, f)/\log r = \infty$ for transcendental entire functions.

In the following I'll write $M(r)$ for $M(r, f)$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $M(1) = 1$. First we apply the Hadamard three-circle theorem to the radii $1 < r < s$:
$$
 \log M(r) \le \frac{\log r}{\log s} \log M(s) \, .
$$
Next we choose $r_0 > 1$ so large that $\log M(r)/\log r > k$ for $r > r_0$.
Then we have for $s > r \ge r_0$:
$$
\begin{align}
 \log M(s) &\ge \frac{\log s}{\log r}\log M(r) \\
& =  \log M(r) + \frac{\log M(r)}{\log r} \cdot \log \frac s r \\
& > \log M(r) +  k \log \frac sr 
\end{align}
$$
and therefore
$$
 \frac{M(s)}{s^k} > \frac{M(r)}{r^k} \, .
$$
